# jquery validation with php form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to use jquery validation for a php form to change your password but I keep getting the error "Your password must be the same as above" when the password is correct. I can't seem to find out where I have went wrong at all... Here's the JS code

```
var changepassword = function() {

    return {
        init: function() {
            /*
             *  Jquery Validation, https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation
             */

            $('#changepassword').validate({
                errorClass: 'help-block animation-slideUp',
                errorElement: 'div',
                errorPlacement: function(error, e) {
                    e.parents('.form-group > div').append(error);
                },
                highlight: function(e) {
                    $(e).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-error').addClass('has-error');
                    $(e).closest('.help-block').remove();
                },
                success: function(e) {
                    if (e.closest('.form-group').find('.help-block').length === 2) {
                        e.closest('.help-block').remove();
                    } else {
                        e.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-error');
                        e.closest('.help-block').remove();
                    }
                },
                rules: {
                    'newpassword': {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 6
                    },
                    'newpassword-verify': {
                        equalTo: '#newpassword',
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    'newpassword': {
                        required: 'Please provide a password',
                        minlength: 'Your password must be at least 6 characters long'
                    },
                    'newpassword-verify': {
                        required: 'Please provide a password',
                        minlength: 'Your password must be at least 6 characters long',
                        equalTo: 'Please enter the same password as above'
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
}();
```

This is the PHP/HTML for the form

```
<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal form-bordered" id="changepassword">
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="newpassword">New Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" id="newpassword" name="newpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="New Password" required>
        </div>
    </div>
   <!-- This is where I keep getting the error -->
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Repeat Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" id="newpassword-verify" name="newpassword-verify" class="form-control" placeholder="Repeat Password" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="oldpassword">Current Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" id="oldpassword" name="oldpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-actions">
        <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Update</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It seems that when I change the JS file and then put it back on the server that the changes are not being made. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was able to fix it by making a new file called settings1.php then removing the old one and renaming the new one with the old name.